# Cannot uninstall ionic using npm on Mac

Tags: npm, ionic-framework, osx-yosemite, ionic2

I am trying to switch to ionic2. Installing on top of my previous installation of ionic 1 appears to succeed (based on the output) but ionic1 remains as shown by ionic info. Here were the steps. Any help would be appreciated.

1. Successfully Installed ionic2@beta using sudo npm install -g ionic@beta
2. ionic -v shows version 1.7.14
3. Uninstalled using npm uninstall -g ionic
4. Successfully (based on printout) uninstalled ionic 2
5. ionic -v shows version 1.7.14 (WTF)
6. Tried 'npm uninstall -g ionic' again
7. Received command prompt immediately, no other outputs (no affect)
8. ionic -v shows version 1.7.14

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With some investigation I found out what was going wrong. At some point earlier I had installed ionic version 1 which got loaded by npm in /usr/local/lib as part of the sub-directory node_modules. Later on when I installed version 2 globally with sudo it installed it in my home directory `~/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/ionic/bin`. The installed program was a node script called `ionic`. The bash alias was still pointing to the version 1 code. I don't know why npm changed the directory. To fix the problem, I did the following:

1. Deleted the folder /usr/local/bin/node_modules/ionic
2. Removed the symbolic link to the alias named `ionic`
3. Re-installed the ionic@beta globally using sudo. This created the node script `ionic` in `~/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/ionic/bin`.
4. Tested it using the full path to the node script `ionic`
5. In the process of creating a symbolic link named `ionic` so I can access the command from anywhere in my home directory.
6. Have to load cordova 4.3 and

I should have found this earlier but I am getting rusty in my command line skills. It turns out that ionic-cli is works for both v1 and v2.

Answer (score 1):

You are using wrong command `ionic2@beta` to install ionic 2. Use

```
$ npm install -g ionic@beta
```

Comment: I think you are mistaken. Here are the results of the 'ionic info' command when I had ionic 2 installed - Note that the CLI version is also a 2. Moreover if I do a 'start' command with --v2, it creates a ionic 1 code.: Cordova CLI: Not installed
Gulp version: CLI version 3.9.0
Gulp local:
Ionic Version: 2.0.0-alpha.57
Ionic CLI Version: 2.0.0-beta.17
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.0.0-beta.8
ios-deploy version: 1.8.2
ios-sim version: 5.0.6
OS: Mac OS X El Capitan
Node Version: v4.2.3
Xcode version: Xcode 7.2.1 Build version 7C1002

Comment: Tried doing it. I am still stuck in 1onic 1 and unable to override it. I am trying to understand where ionic 1 is installed. I am going to cleanup directory by directory.

Comment: Hi Syed Tarig, Did you find any solution?. If so please post it here. It will be very useful.

Comment: Unfortunately I am still stuck.

Comment: That is exactly the command I am using but with sudo. It turns out that sudo is needed unless you do some special procedure document in the npm website

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
sudo npm uninstall -g ionic
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me on ubuntu 16,

to remove cordova, ionic:

```
sudo npm uninstall -g cordova    
sudo npm uninstall -g ionic
```

and for npm:

```
sudo npm uninstall npm -g
```

hope it will work

Answer (score 0):

For mac user delete this folders.

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic
/usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules/ionic
```

Answer (score -1):

As you could install it with

`npm install -g ionic`

you should uninstall it with

`npm uninstall -g ionic`

Comment: As written in the question, OP has already tried this command without success.